# extracting chars from string using regex and pythonic way

Tags: python, regex

I have a string like this: "32H74312"
I want to extract some parts and put them in different variables.

```
first_part = 32 # always 2 digits
second_part = H # always 1 chars
third_part = 743 # always 3 digit 
fourth_part = 12 # always 2 digit
```

Is there some way to this in pythonic way?

Answer (score 2):

There's now reason to use a regex for such a simple task.
The *pythonic* way could be something like:

```
string = "32H74312"
part1 = string[:2]
part2 = string[2:3]
part3 = string[3:6]
part4 = string[6:]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a fixed amount of characters to capture you can do:

```
(\d\d)(\w)(\d{3})(\d\d)
```

You can then utilize `re.match`.

```
pattern = r"(\d\d)(\w)(\d{3})(\d\d)"
string = "32H74312"

first_part, second_part, third_part, fourth_part = re.match(pattern, string).groups()

print(first_part, second_part, third_part, fourth_part)
```

Which outputs:

```
32 H 743 12
```

Unless it's because you want an easy way to enforce each part being digits and word characters. Then this isn't really something you need regex for.

Answer (score 1):

If String is always same length, then you can do this:

```
string =  "32H74312"
first_part = string[:2] #always 2 digits
second_part = string[2:-5] # always 1 chars
third_part = string[3:-2] # always 3 digit 
fourth_part = string[:6] # always 2 digit
```

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [Pedro's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43291829/7256039), string slicing syntax is the best way to go.

However, having variables like `first_part`, `second_part`, . . . `nth_part` is typically considered an anti-pattern; you are probably looking for a **tuple** instead:

```
str = "32H74312"
parts = (str[:2], str[2], str[3:6], str[6:])

print(parts)
print(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2], parts[3])
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite 'pythonic' also :

```
string = "32H74312"
parts = {0:2, 2:3, 3:6, 3:6, 6:8 } 
string_parts = [ string[ p : parts[p] ] for p in parts ]
```

Comment: Another way to go: `parts = [string[a:b] for a, b in {0:2, 2:3, 3:6, 3:6, 6:8 }.items()]`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method:

```
import re

line = '32H74312'

d2p = r'(\d\d)' # two digits pattern
ocp = r'(\w)' # one char pattern
d3p = r'(\d{3})' # three digits pattern

lst = re.match(d2p + ocp + d3p + d2p, line).groups()
for item in lst:
    print(item)
```

Brackets are necessary for grouping search elements. Also to make testing your regexps more comfortable, you can use special platforms such as regex101